# Messenger running old version of bot service

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger, azure-bot-service

I'm building a bot on the azure bot service and have successfully integrated it to run on Messenger. However, the messenger version that is running seems to be a much older version. After I have updated the bot service it runs perfectly in the azure test but the messenger version remains on the older version.

I've tried to remove all the integration and add it again but I can't seem to get it to update when I need it to.

Is there some other step that I'm missing that is required to get it to deploy or update in messenger?

Comment: That is strange.  You could try stopping, and restarting the service in Azure after deployment.  Or, re-configure the Facebook channel.  If it is a caching issue, that might force a refresh.  I haven't heard of this before.

Comment: It seems to have come right now after starting and stopping a couple of times. I'll let you know if it happens again.